# Why I failed to register new user on Firebase?

Tags: java, android

Hello, I am new to android apps development.
I am using android studio version 3.0.1 and firebase.

**Before this I can register my user.**
**But recently I cannot register new user.**

**What should I do ?
Can somebody help me.**

Here is my code snippet.

It only shows this **"Could not register. Please try again"**

```java
public class PSregister extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private Button buttonRegister;
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private ImageButton mPSProfileImage;
    private EditText mNameText;
    private EditText mPhoneNoText;
    private EditText mLocationText;
    private EditText mSSM;
    private TextView textViewSignIn;


    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private Uri mImageUri = null;

    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;



    PSDA Helper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_psregister);

        firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Helper = new PSDA(mDatabase);

        mPSProfileImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.psEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.psPwd);
        mNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.psName);
        mPhoneNoText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.psPNum);
        mLocationText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.psAdd);
        mSSM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SSMLicense);

        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
        textViewSignIn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSignIn);

        mPSProfileImage.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                registerUser();
            }
        });

        textViewSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v == textViewSignIn) {
                    //open login activity
                    startActivity(new Intent(PSregister.this,psLogin .class));
                }
            }
        });

    }




    private void registerUser() {
        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        final String name = mNameText.getText().toString().trim();
        final String pNum = mPhoneNoText.getText().toString().trim();
        final String loc = mLocationText.getText().toString().trim();
        final String SSM= mSSM.getText().toString().trim();


        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            //email empty
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            //password empty
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pNum)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter phone number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(loc)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(SSM)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter SSM License",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        //if validation ok
        //will show progress bar
        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User...");
        progressDialog.show();

        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        //checking if successful
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            //registered
                            String psId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            startPosting(psId, email, password);

                            Toast.makeText(PSregister.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), psLogin.class));

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(PSregister.this, "Could not register. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
    }


    private void startPosting(final String psId, final String Email, final  String password) {



        final String psname = mNameText.getText().toString();
        final String psPNum = mPhoneNoText.getText().toString();
        final String psAdd = mLocationText.getText().toString();
        final String psSSM = mSSM.getText().toString();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(psname) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(psPNum) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(psAdd) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(psSSM)
                && mImageUri != null){

            StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("psimageProfile").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

            filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();

                    PS ps = new PS(downloadUrl.toString(),psId, Email, password, psname, psPNum, psAdd, psSSM );

                    Helper.CreatePS(ps, psId);


                }
            });
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            mImageUri = data.getData();

            mPSProfileImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why can't you? do you get an error?

Comment: Its only show me this message. " Could not register. Please try again" and no error.

Comment: try to check what error are you getting with `task.getException()`. then update your question. We cannot help until we know what the problem is.

Comment: debug and check in your code what goes wrong. if you want more clear error messages, you'll have to implement them

Comment: Thank you for your solution @M.WaqasPervez. I found that the problem is I should key in the password in 6 character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Your password must be more then 6 character or digits** and also required a strong 
>     password.
>
> Email must be unique every time.